# Is the following claim on O(n) correct?

Tags: algorithm, function, time-complexity, big-o

My professor said that it can't happen `a(n)=O(b(n))` and at the same time: `b(n)=O(a(n))` but why is that? according to the definition there is no contradiction at all.

The first says from some point `a(n)<= alpha * b(n)` and the second says from some other point `b(n)<= beta * a(n)`

Comment: You *can* have `a(n)=O(b(n))` and `b(n)=O(a(n))` at the same time. That's pretty much the definition of big theta. But as OmG points out, maybe the professor meant to say that `a(n)=o(b(n))` and `b(n)=o(a(n))` can't be true at the same time. That's a difference between bigO and littleO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not correct. Because it is an alternative definition of `Theta` notation. Hence, if `a(n) = O(b(n))` and `b(n) = O(a(n))`, we will have `a(n) \in Theta(b(n))` and vice versa. For example, `a(n) = b(n) = n`. So, `a(n), b(n) \in O(n)`. Hence, `a(n) \in O(b(n))` and `b(n) \in O(a(n))`.

However, note that if we have `o` (little-oh) in replace of `O` (big-oh), the claim is correct!